# python dictionary adding to an existing key

Tags: python, dictionary, append

I am trying to add items to a dictionary. I have already tried many of the things that have been suggested but nothing seems to be working.
This is my current version of the code.

For key "1", there will be three entries. But as I go through a list and try adding items to key '1", it simply replaces the value not append.

Comment: try:
          if chiChange1 not in chiChangeDict[res1]:
    
            chiChangeDict[res1].append(chiChange1)
        except:
          chiChangeDict[res1]=chiChange1
 
        print chiChangeDict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d.setdefault('1', []).append('x')
>>> d.setdefault('1', []).append('y')
>>> d.setdefault('1', []).append('z')
>>> d
{'1': ['x', 'y', 'z']}
```

or using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['1'].append('x')
>>> d['1'].append('y')
>>> d['1'].append('z')
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['x', 'y', 'z']})
```